# Andl with a parameter in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $36, %esp               // allocate 36 bytes for local vars
movl    8(%ebp), %eax           // eax = n
andl    $1, %eax                // how can u andl a parameter? parameter can be greater than 1
testl   %eax, %eax
jmp .L4
cmpl $2, 8(%ebp)
jne .L6

.L4:
movl    8(%ebp), %eax           //eax = n
movl    %eax, -28(%ebp)         //x = eax
movl    $1431655766, -32(%ebp)  //y = 1431655766
movl    -32(%ebp), %eax         //eax = y
imull   -28(%ebp)               //edx = x * eax
movl    %edx, %ecx              //ecx = edx
movl    -28(%ebp), %eax         //eax = x
sarl    $31, %eax               //eax = eax >> 31
movl    %ecx, %edx              //edx = ecx
subl    %eax, %edx              //edx = edx - eax
movl    %edx, -24(%ebp)         //z = edx
movl    -24(%ebp), %eax         //eax = z
addl    %eax, %eax              //eax = eax+eax
addl    -24(%ebp), %eax         //eax = z+eax
movl    -28(%ebp), %ecx         //ecx = x
subl    %eax, %ecx              //ecx = ecx-eax
movl    %ecx, -24(%ebp)         //z = ecx
cmpl    $0, -24(%ebp)           //compare z and 0
jne .L7                         //if not equal jmp to .L7
cmpl    $3, 8(%ebp)             //compare n and 3
jne .L6                         //if not equal jmp .L6
```

Okay I have this assembly snippet, and I'm wondering how you can `andl` $1 and a parameter, the parameter can be greater than 1. Also the `testl` seems useless, because `jmp` jumps regardless. Any thoughts?

**Edit:** I've updated the code, not sure if correct reasoning for all of it. Very confused about `imull -28(%ebp)`

Comment: Compiled with or without optimization?

Comment: this should be w/o optimization.

Comment: Don't be surprised to find the occasional useless instruction in unoptimized assembly dumps.

Comment: i've updated the .L4, do you mind checking my comments to see if i made any mistakes?

Comment: Your comments have inconsistent variable names.  Sometimes you have `-28(%ebp)` commented as `x` and sometimes as `y`.

Comment: yeah, i fixxed it. any input on the imull? not sure if i reasoned that correctly

Comment: If I recall correctly, `imull` creates a result in two registers (high half and low half).  Depending on the size of the inputs, high half might always be zero though.

Answer (score 0):

[`AND`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_12.html) can take an 8 or 32-bit immediate, so there's nothing prevents you from ANDing eax with 0x1

`TEST` sets the flags for using later, you don't have to use it right away. You don't provide the code at L4 but there's probably some instruction checking that
Edit: As the above was an unoptimized build, don't expect it to be efficient.

[`IMUL`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_138.html) with one parameter and suffix `l` multiplies that param with EAX. You need to read about x86 instructions if you want to deal with assembly.

Comment: theres actually 2 more lines after that snippet: `cmpl $2, 8(ebp)` `jne .L6`

Answer (score 0):

`$1` a short form of a constant (number) without leading zeros. In a 32-bit-environment (%eax!) it is equivalent to `0x00000001` and means: set all bits except the rightmost to zero, let the rightmost bit untouched. Here it is probably used to isolate a boolean value (0=false or 1=true) or to determine the oddness (0=even, 1=odd).